# Is it possible to use Gtk.TreeModelFilter with editable columns?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm trying to implement a `TreeView`, that can be both filtered and edited, without success. The `Gtk.TreeModelFilter` is not implementing `SetValue()` functions. I have tried to create a new class having `Gtk.TreeModelFilter` as it's base and to create a new `SetValue()` method, but it is not called from the `TreeView` (always the `Gtk.TreeModelFilter`'s method is called). How can I implement a filter for `TreeView` that can do this?

Comment: I think posting a little code about what you've tried would help.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value you are trying to set?

Tree view ui objects usually require you to set up a tree of objects before they can render.
Sometimes you build new leaves through the tree api; sometimes, it is an object.

Example of a tree object:

```
{ name: 'Maurice', 
  children: [ 
    { name: 'Mark', children: [ 
      { name: 'Molly', children: [] },
      { name: 'Drew', children: [] },   
      { name: 'Craig ', children: [] }]}]}
```

Comment: It has to be able to modify any of the columns. It displays a collection of words and some parameters in a hierarchical order. But I have also to filter the displayed content to make it easier to find the desired row.